# Codeblocks doesn't run on Mac El Capitan

Tags: macos, codeblocks

I upgraded to OSX El capitan yesterday and now my codeblocks doesn't run anymore. It build as usual but when i try to run the file nothing just happens. So what should i do?

I use codeblocks 13.12

```
Checking for existence: /Users/Leo.Byskata/Documents/skola/cprog/jieba/bin/Debug/jieba 
Executing: osascript -e 'tell app "Terminal"' -e 'activate' -e 'do script "/Users/Leo.Byskata/Desktop/CodeBlocks.app/Contents/MacOS/cb_console_runner DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=$DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH:. /Users/Leo.Byskata/Documents/skola/cprog/jieba/bin/Debug/jieba "' -e 'end tell' (in /Users/Leo.Byskata/Documents/skola/cprog/jieba/.)
```

Comment: hecking for existence: /Users/Leo.Byskata/Documents/skola/cprog/jieba/bin/Debug/jieba
Executing: osascript -e 'tell app "Terminal"' -e 'activate' -e 'do script "/Users/Leo.Byskata/Desktop/CodeBlocks.app/Contents/MacOS/cb_console_runner DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=$DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH:. /Users/Leo.Byskata/Documents/skola/cprog/jieba/bin/Debug/jieba "' -e 'end tell'  (in /Users/Leo.Byskata/Documents/skola/cprog/jieba/.)

Comment: If you have further background you wish to add to your question please edit your question and add it rather than using comments.

Comment: Added info from a comment under the question. Added to title.